# how to write html tags in a c# string

Tags: c#, html, css

I want to include the following HTML code in my C# code:

```
<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Authorized.</span>
```

However, when I include it in my C# code as is, it's getting transformed into the following:

```
&lt;span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"&gt;Authorized.&lt;/span&gt;
```

When I try to display this message on the C# side, I'm getting this result: it's changing the < sign to "&l-t;" instead.

That's why I can't display it in red and bold on the screen; I'm just printing a sentence with a  tag as plain text.

In c# code

```
 string message = "<span style=\"color: red; font-weight: bold;\">Authorized.</span>";
    
    BaseMessage = new BaseMessage()
    {
        Kod = "1",
        Mesaj = message,
        Tip = MesajTipi.Hata,
        Yer = "X"
    };
```

The picture I want to see is this

[image]

But what I see is this picture

[image]

Comment: Is this a web application? If so, which framework?

Comment: Hi, yes this is a web app, i use services for frontend, this message from backend, and .net framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your html is not encoded you can use @Html.Raw(message).
If it is encoded you have to do the following :
Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(message));

Comment: it was useful information, but is it possible to do this without using the library ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a div in html, you can do this way:

```
 string message = "<span style=\"color: red; font-weight: bold;\">Authorized.</span>";
 idofyourdiv.InnerHtml = message;
```

Comment: i need to do this on the .net side so c#. The innerHTML part is used as JavaScript